# Return Cell Reference from Lookup Formula without using Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that records daily sales quantities over a time period, and I'd like to calculate average daily sales, but exclude the days before we started selling a product since they all return 0.

I have the below lookup function that returns the value from the last cell in the row containing a value greater that 0.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(F5:L5>0),F5:L5)
```

Is there a way to return the cell reference of this formula? I think I could then use this with indirect() to create a variable average range.

I've tried a few index match lookups, but this hasn't worked for me because if the last value is a duplicate of an early value, it shortens the total range I want to use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(F5:L5,1,MATCH(2,1/(F5:L5>0),F5:L5)))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

---

In the formula above `INDEX(F5:L5,1,MATCH(2,1/(F5:L5>0),F5:L5))` returns *cell reference* of result and `CELL(..)` returns address.

*Cell reference* means that you can use it somehow like this (depends on your needs):

```
=AVERAGE(F5:INDEX(F5:L5,1,MATCH(2,1/(F5:L5>0),F5:L5)))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

If `INDEX` returns reference to, say, cell `J5`, formula evaluates to `=AVERAGE(F5:J5)`