# Return the row of first non-blank cell

Tags: excel

Let's say I have the array A1:A5 in excel:

```
    A  
1    
2  
3  'test'  
4  
5  'test2'
```

How can I return "3"? I'm looking for something in Excel formulas. The blanks are genuine blanks.

Comment: Are the blanks in that column "genuine" blanks, or the null string ("") e.g. as a result of formulas within those cells? Also, are the entries in that column all text, or are there numbers as well?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you looking for something in excel or vba?

Comment: None of the answer thus far work if the blanks are the result of formulas.

Comment: Yes - though the OP answered my question by amending their post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to return the actual value ("test" in this case"):

```
=INDEX(A1:A13,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A1:A13<>0),0),0))
```

Source: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2104-excel-return-first-last-non-blank-cell-in-row-column.html#a1

(Note: adjust the "A13" as needed.)

You can pass this into CELL to get the address like you're looking for ($A$3).

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A13,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A1:A13<>0),0),0)))
```

Source: [Return Cell Reference from Lookup Formula without using Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565746/return-cell-reference-from-lookup-formula-without-using-match)

If you need literally just "3" like you asked, you can use ROW in combination with the first example

```
=ROW(INDEX(A1:A13,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A1:A13<>0),0),0)))
```

Source: https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d

Comment: Nice!  But I should vote you down just for the kitty avatar.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no numerics within the range:

`=MATCH("*",A:A,0)`

Regards